# C# how can i get all users of the XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have created an xml file and there are stored my user. The problem, I only ever get the first one out. How do I manage to get all users of the XML file displayed?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = "C:\\temp\\Accounts.xml";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
        XmlElement user = doc.CreateElement("user");
        user.InnerText = textBox1.Text;


        root.AppendChild(user);
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(root);
        doc.Save(path);
        MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load("C:\\temp\\Accounts.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode person in xdoc.SelectNodes("/Login"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(person["user"].InnerText);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Show your XML file will help us.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what wasn't working for you, but this works for me. I am using `//Login` as the path selector. Ensure that your XML file actually has multiple users.

```
void Main()
{
    //Create();
    View();

    // Output:
    // User1
    // User2
}

private void Create()
{
    string path = "C:\\Code\\Sandbox\\Accounts.xml";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
    XmlElement user = doc.CreateElement("user");
    user.InnerText = "User2";
    root.AppendChild(user);
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(root);
    doc.Save(path);
    Console.WriteLine("Created SuccesFully!");
}

private void View()
{
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("C:\\Code\\Sandbox\\Accounts.xml");
    foreach (XmlNode person in xdoc.SelectNodes("//Login"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person["user"].InnerText);
    }
}
```

Here is the generated XML. I inserted a root `Logins` element.

```xml
<Logins>
  <Login>
    <user>User1</user>
  </Login>
  <Login>
    <user>User2</user>
  </Login>
</Logins>
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Can someone tell me if I can check as contains, if the user is already in the xml file zufinden?

Comment: Use the code in the `View()` method to get the existing users as a `List<string>` and check your new user against that list using the `Contains()` method.